# Divide by pointer value and comment symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have this case:

```
int a=5;
int b=6;
int *p_a=&a;
int *p_b=&b

std::cout << *p_a / *p_b;
```

which seems fine. However, if I delete the space between the division symbol `/` and `*p_a` like this:

```
std::cout << *p_a /*p_b;
```

The compiler understands `/*` as comment.

Is this behavior a standard one? I do not even have `*/` as a closing symbol of the comment.

Note: I am on MSVS 2013.

**Edit:**

It seems to be a standard behaviour since SO code formating has considered it as a comment also :D

Comment: The C++ tokenizer is supposed to be *greedy* and collect as many characters it can into tokens. So the compiler is correct. It doesn't matter that there's no closing `*/`, that will just make the compiler complain about an unterminated comment or something similar.

Comment: no it is not compiling I am getting compile error and intellisense errors :
error C1071: unexpected end of file found in comment
IntelliSense: comment unclosed at end of file

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean as many characters in one token or as many tokens in the whole translation unit?

Comment: As many characters as possible to form a single token. In this case it sees `/`,`*` and `p` without separation, and since there is no token `/*p` it backtracks to `/*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard behaviour. Draft n4296 says in 2.7 Comments [lex.comment]

> The characters `/*` start a comment, which terminates with the characters */. These comments do not nest...

That means that if you remove the space between `/` and `*` any conformant C++ compiler will see it as the leading sequence of a (here unterminated) comment.